# What does head.next actually mean in linked lists?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, tree, queue, stack

I have created a linked list with a `Node` class having `Node next` and `int data`.

What does `head.next` mean? I'm confused.

Consider this list: 1 > 2 > 3 > 4, and 1 is the head.

Now if I execute `head=head.next`, `head` is now pointing to 2. But when I execute `head.next=null`, 1 is pointing to `null`. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: It is not possible to answer without seeing your code. Please construct a [example]. Going off by variable names alone, `head.next` is the node after the head node.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to visualise things.

> Consider this list: 1 > 2 > 3 > 4, and 1 is the head.

```
 head
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

> if I execute `head=head.next`, `head` is now pointing to 2

```
                  head
                   ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

> but when I execute `head.next=null`, 1 is pointing to `null`.

```
 head
  ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
│ next: null│    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: null│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

In conclusion:

- when you assign a value to `head`, you change what `head` refers to. This does not affect any `next` reference: the links between the nodes remain unchanged. You just might have lost access to the first node when `head` was the only reference to it. And in that case you actually make the list one node shorter*, as it now starts at 2.

  *<sub>(When a node becomes unreachable, it no longer has any practical use. The garbage collector may free the memory it occupied.)</sub>
- when you don't assign a value to `head`, but do `head.next =`, then you assign a value to a *property* of the node that `head` references, and *that* affects the list. This is called *mutation*. On the other hand, `head` will still refer to node 1, since you didn't assign a value to the `head` variable.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are referring to the linked list example below

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* second = NULL;
    Node* third = NULL;

    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;

    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

here Node is a class in which a pointer of that node class next is declared and a integer type data is used to store the data values that the next pointer will point to

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

head here is an object of class Node which is created and by using its pointer declared inside of it previosly, we point to a next Node object second using head.next = second. So now the pointer of our head object is pointing to the address of our second object we created, this way the head object is linked with our second object. data variable is used to store the value given to every object or in this case every node

```
    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;

    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;
```

comming to your second point, i don't get it why would you point head.next to head(itself) and head.next = NULL gives nothing as you have to point the pointer to a second object to create a linked list.